# Different rewrite rules for taxonomies and cp in multisite?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I´m making a multilingual site with multisite and I`m wondering if you can specify different rewrite rules for taxonomies and custom posts for the different sites, that are using the same theme. Maybe check if a certain subdomain is used and then use different rewrites?

Suggestions?

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful? Do you still miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a translated slug:

```
// Use a translated slug in pretty permalinks
'rewrite'              => array (
    'slug'       => _x( 'default-slug', 'slug', 'your_text_domain' ),
    'with_front' => FALSE
),
```

In your translation you can change the slug now like everything else.